# Web App Azure AD Authentication Sign Out going to No Page Found 404

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, authentication, azure-active-directory

I am using a Web App for which I have implemented AD Authentication from the Authentication Tab in App Service. I have followed below link for Sigin and Signout functionality.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-customize-sign-in-out

I dont have any issues for Redirect URL : /.auth/login/aad/callback

But when I use /.auth/logout for Signout, I am navigating to page Not found error.

References I am using is Microsoft.Identity.Web

(Based on my company Audit, we have to enable Authentication in App Service, while doing so it is expecting redirect url to be /.auth/login/aad/callback. So I have followed above url for this implementation).

Comment: After sign out the user is taken to `/.auth/logout/done`. Are you expecting the same or have you overridden the post-logout URL as suggested [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-customize-sign-in-out#sign-out-of-a-session)?

Comment: I tried this. But after hitting Signout button, I am going to 404 page not found page. Do we need to add any inbuild UI classes ?

<a href="/.auth/logout">Sign out</a>

Answer (score 0):

The document you mentioned in the question is based on the `built-in authentication and authorization in App Service`, so you need to follow [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad) to do some configurations in azure web app.

By the way, if you'd like to integrate azure ad to your asp.net core app, I recommend you to follow [this sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code#web-applications) to realize it. And you need to set the custom sign out url, just follow the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56740143/how-to-specify-custom-logout-url-when-using-azure-ad-authentication-in-net-core)：using url `rewrite middle` to redirect the request or write `your own sign out action`.